# www.odata.stackexchange.com does not exist?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer

I've recently found out that `www.odata.stackexchange.com` does not work while `odata.stackexchange.com` does.

Now I know the `www` prefix isn't liked, but it should exist, and simply redirect to `odata.stackexchange.com`. For those of us who are used to/accidentally type www at the beginning, this is really annoying.

Comment: I wouldn't classify this as "really annoying", unless you *keep* doing it...in which case I don't think DNS is the problem :)

Comment: Maybe really annoying was a bit much, buts its still annoying. Were talking <5 minutes fix this.

Comment: Just type the `www` at the end... you'll be much more amused - http://odata.stackexchange.com/www

Comment: IMO, this is a feature request, not a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, thanks to you, anybody with that problem in the future will find this question and know they have to remove the www.

Answer (score 3):

In related news, these also do not exist:

`nothing.odata.stackexchange.com`
`zip.odata.stackexchange.com`
`zilch.odata.stackexchange.com`
`bupkis.odata.stackexchange.com`
`unicornterror.odata.stackexchange.com`

Comment: `evilpumpkin.odata.stackexchange.com` also not working

Comment: Why can't you just have `www` redirect to the non-www version like practically every other site out there? Why is it hated so much? The Prefix `www` is pushed out on commercials, websites, blogs, auto-fixing url tools in software, etc. Your ignoring a standard here.

Comment: BTW, www.reader.google.com exists, www.stackoverflow.com exists, www.stackexchange.com exists, www.mail.yahoo.com exists, www.thedailywtf.com exists, www.microsoft.com exists, www.en.wikipedia.com exists, www.msdn.microsoft.com exists, www.us.php.net exists, etc etc etc. So why is SO the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Though I get the whole `www` thing I don't think it makes sense for sites that already have 3 parts like: `foo.bar.com`.

If we went with allowing this then we would have to do `www.chat.stackoverflow.com` and `www.blog.stackexchange.com` etc .... where would this *madness* stop?

Answer (score -2):

Uhm... couldn't you edit your hosts file?

Comment: Uhm... who downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this does strike me as a very impractical solution

Comment: @Jeff: Ya, but it's a rediculous question :)